# text valu empty giv my only succes

Tags: jquery

When I need to check your content whether it is empty or not, if it is empty then comes the bare back and give me success.

It will in no way forward and tells me that there is a fault with the lack of content.

Problems are just the only show my alarm even though I have empty, email, password, first name and last name and age.

```
$(function () {
$('#clickUserCreate').click(function() {
    var Email = $.trim($('#Email').val(null));
    var Password = $.trim($('#passwordVal').val(null));
    var FirstName = $.trim($('#Firstname').val(null));
    var LastName = $.trim($('#Lastname').val(null));
    var Age = $.trim($('#Age').val());

    //Check
    if(Email == "" && Password == "" && FirstName == "" && LastName == "" && Age == "")
    {
        //error here
        $('.OutError').html('Please enter all fields.');
    }
    else
    {
        //succes her
        //The only show it here!
        alert("Succes");
    }
})
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do things like `var Email = $.trim($('#Email').val(null));` you're setting `Email` equal to `null`. Your logical check `Email == ""` fails because a null value is not equal to an empty string. Also, you're checking whether ALL of your input fields are empty. You will still get a success if some (but not all) of the fields are empty. Try the following instead. It will always return an error until ALL of the fields are filled in.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#clickUserCreate').click(function() {
        var Email = $.trim($('#Email').val());
        var Password = $.trim($('#passwordVal').val());
        var FirstName = $.trim($('#Firstname').val());
        var LastName = $.trim($('#Lastname').val());
        var Age = $.trim($('#Age').val());

        //Check
        if(Email == "" || Password == "" || FirstName == "" || LastName == "" || Age == "")
        {
            //error here
            $('.OutError').html('Please enter all fields.');
        }
        else
        {
            //succes her
            //The only show it here!
            $('.OutError').html('');
            alert("Succes");
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="OutError"></p>

<input type="text" id="Email" />
<input type="text" id="passwordVal" />
<input type="text" id="Firstname" />
<input type="text" id="Lastname" />
<input type="text" id="Age" />

<button id="clickUserCreate">Create User</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Unbelievable that I not only see the mistakes. Hope you will give me +1 for the question.